# Laravel4 error: Class Illuminate\Foundation\Application contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm gettin this error after composer update (and the consequent autoload generator):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class Illuminate\Foundation\Application contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Support\Contracts\ResponsePreparerInterface::readyForResponses)
```

I have a clean install with these dependencies

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "cartalyst/sentry": "2.1.*"
    },
```

If i switch to "laravel/framework": "4.1.*", this error is fixed. What happened to 4.0.* ?

Comment: Did you do `composer dump-autoload` after the install?

Comment: Yeah, i did. No errors, but then any php call triggers that error

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: 5.3.x Anyway it did work before last composer update